# How to align Text to the start of an element

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am new to compose. I need some UI helps while building a signup page.
This is the snippet I've implemented.

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(0.dp, 50.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp)
        .width(Max)
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {

    
    Row(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.1F))
        OutlinedTextField(
            label = {
                Text(
                    text = "First Name",
                    style = TextStyle(fontSize = Dimens.body4)
                )
            },
            value = firstName,
            onValueChange = { firstName = it },
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(0.5F)
                .padding(1.dp)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.1F))

        OutlinedTextField(
            label = {
                Text(
                    text = "Last Name",
                    style = TextStyle(fontSize = Dimens.body4)
                )
            },
            value = lastName,
            onValueChange = { lastName = it },
            modifier = Modifier.weight(0.5F)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.1F))
    }
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(Dimens.grid_3_5))
    OutlinedTextField(
        label = {
            if (isPhoneSignup)
                Text(
                    text = phone,
                    style = TextStyle(fontSize = Dimens.body4)
                )
            else
                Text(
                    text = email,
                    style = TextStyle(fontSize = Dimens.body4)
                )
        },
        leadingIcon = {
            if (isPhoneSignup)
            Icon(
                imageVector = Filled.Phone,
                contentDescription = null
            )
            else
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Filled.Email,
                    contentDescription = null
                )
        },
        value = login,
        onValueChange = { login = it },
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(Dimens.grid_1))

    ClickableText(text = AnnotatedString(loginTypeText),
        onClick = {
            isPhoneSignup = !isPhoneSignup
        }
    )
}
```

I got the result like this. [image]

What I really to achieve is

1.`Login with Phone Number` Text at the same start of `Email TextField` while TextField is center horizontally.

2. Make the `first name` + `last name` Text Field to the exact same size of `Email TextField` .Those 2 TextFields take more space than `Email TextField` in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width size is defined by the `Column`, then apply `fillMaxWidth()` to the children to be sure to fill the entire width.
Then in your Row you can use `Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp, Alignment.CenterHorizontally)` to avoid the use of Spacer inside:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding( horizontal= 20.dp )
        .fillMaxWidth() //your custom width
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {

    Row(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp, Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    ) {

        OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        )

        OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        )

    }

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

    OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

    ClickableText(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    )
}
```

[image]